# Vanilla JavaScript For Loop to push array of names

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Mock Mark up:

```
 <div class="post">
   <a name="1234"></a>
 </div>
```

Remember this is mock markup of course there is more html in the above, this a is the first a tag inside the parent `.post`

Here is my code:

```
var pid = []; 
var post = document.getElementsByClassName('post');
  for(var i=0;i<post.length;i++){
    var postId = post[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttributeNode('name');
    pid.push(postId);
   }
 alert(pid);
```

I keep getting literally `,,,,,,`

I have tried `.getAttribute` and `.getAttributeNode`

Is there something I am doing wrong here? I am trying to make an array of "names" persay to classify these later on using an ID specification.

Any suggestions thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is the problem here. What do you mean by *"I keep getting literally `,,,,,,`"*? That's the `alert` content? Try `console.log()`, it usually yields clearer info about the variable. What was the difference between the results from `.getAttribute` and `.getAttributeNode`?

Comment: .getAttribute alerts nothing Node alerts commas like its getting the data its just undefined or something

Comment: yeah, well, I can't reproduce your error, your code works for me when using `getAttribute`: http://jsfiddle.net/pQE2X/1/

Comment: You are providing us with a broken HTML in: It's not your actually HTML, and that is the problem!

Comment: It is basically the actual HTML as after the parent is a div, then the a tag then some other divs. So .getElementsByTagName('a')[0] is perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did everything right but you forgot the `.value`:

```
var pid = []; 
var post = document.getElementsByClassName('post');
for(var i=0;i<post.length;i++){
    var postId = post[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttributeNode('name').value;
    pid.push(postId);
 }
 alert(pid);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/A6R9H/)

Comment: Oh really? We need to place .value with this? I thought that was only for like inputs and textareas haha. Thanks man I'll try it out right now!

Answer (score 1):

You can use .value as Tom mentioned or you can use .getAttribute('name').

You would need to modify your code a little bit further for it work for more than one anchor in .post class:

```
<div class="post">
   <a name="1234"></a>
   <a name="5678"></a>
   <a name="9123"></a>
 </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var pid = []; 
var post = document.getElementsByClassName('post');
  for(var i=0;i<post.length;i++){
    var anchors = post[i].getElementsByTagName('a');    
    for(var j=0; j<anchors.length; j++){
       var name = anchors[j].getAttribute('name');
       pid.push(name);
    }    
}

for(var i=0;i<pid.length;i++){
    alert(pid[i]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/joybroto/3d9qz/7/